# for each loop to iterate through all the sites which are available

Tags: vb.net

I want to add a linq query that will iterate through all sites and return records per site

I tried using an if statement but its not working appropriately. The loop must go through the sites which are available and it must be a linq query on a datatable to return the results

```vb
If Site = "All Sites" Or Site = "" And siteFilter = "B" Then
    If reportCode = "A" Then
        reportCode = "D"
    ElseIf reportCode = "B" Then
        reportCode = "E"
    Else
        reportCode = "F"
    End If
End If
dt = rb.GetTop20ProductsReportDT(startDate, endDate, SiteCodeList, Site, TopNum, reportCode, Session("GroupName"))
Session("CPTop20ProductsDT") = dt
... if the reportCode is A which represents "per Site".. linq query to return record per site
```

Comment: `For Each Dim site in availableSites` ?

Comment: Post the code you tried out and point out where it failed to do what you expected it to do.

Comment: @YolulaSisilana: don't comment your own question but edit it ;-)

Comment: I suspect that you want `If (Site = "All Sites" OrElse Site = "") AndAlso siteFilter = "B" Then`. `And` (and `AndAlso`, which is the version you should use for logical conditions) has a higher *precedence* than `Or` (and `OrElse`, which again is the version to use for logical conditions). More info: [Operator Precedence in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/operator-precedence).